# How to downgrade bundler or upgrade rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler, omniauth, gem-bundler

I added omniauth gem to my gemfile and tried to run bundle install, but got a message about incompatibility of rails and bundler versions. I tried to update rails, but got messages about incompatibility with other gems. How can I downgrade bundler to 1.0?

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/......
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.0) ruby depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.1.1)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
```

and

```
$ bundle update rails
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/......
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    factory_girl_rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.1.1)
```

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Try the following commands:

```
gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler --version '1.0.0'
```

Comment: `Gem bundler-2.1.2 cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem`

Answer (score 32):

To install downgraded version of bundler, try:

```
gem install bundler --version '<= 0.10.6'
```

so you could have both version installed (check: `gem list bundler`/`bundler _0.9.26_ -v`), then run using that specific version, e.g.:

```
bundle _0.9.26_ install
```

Learn more: [How to upgrade/downgrade Rubygems](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/UPGRADING_rdoc.html) at rubyforge

Answer (score 8):

If you want downgrade or upgrade your `bundler`
There are some problem when we are trying to uninstall global bundler version. I solve this problem of my own technique. Follow the steps:

**Step-1:** run: `gem list bundler`

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bundler (2.0.2, 1.17.3)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
```

I have 2 bundler version here 2.0.2 and 1.17.3. Now I uninstall 2.0.2 because I will use 1.17.3. But when I am trying to uninstall 2.0.2 using this command `gem uninstall bundler --version '2.0.2'` I find an error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
bundler is not installed in GEM_HOME, try:
    gem uninstall -i /home/habib/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global bundler
```

because It is my global bundler. But Error message have the solution. then I try step 2.

**Step-2:** run `gem uninstall -i /home/habib/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global bundler`

**output:** `Successfully uninstalled bundler-2.0.2`

**step-3:** I check my bundler list again run `gem list bundler`

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.17.3)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
capistrano-bundler (1.2.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
```

Here I have only one bundler `1.17.3` and I can use it my any project

check your bundler version: run `bundler -v`

`output:` `Bundler version 1.17.3`

Answer (score 8):

**Step 1**: install the older version (e.g. `1.17.3`) with:

```sh
gem install bundler --version '1.17.3'
```

**Step 2**: uninstall the newer version with:

```sh
gem uninstall bundler
```

Answer (score 6):

To downgrade just type `gem uninstall bundler` it will display:

```
Select gem to uninstall:
 1. bundler-1.13.7
 2. bundler-1.14.4
 3. bundler-1.16.4
 4. bundler-2.0.2
 5. All versions
```

Just select the version you want to uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

gem uninstall bundler -v 2.2.0
worked for me