# Error when installing gem bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation, bundler

I tried to install a ruby application. when it comes to a point where I install a bundle, I get the following error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (>= 0) ruby depends on
      bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0) ruby

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.1.4)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
```

when I tried gem install bundler everything seems to be correct with the following output

```
Successfully installed bundler-1.6.2
1 gem installed
```

but after re-entering install bundle, i get the same error as above... even when i uninstall bundler, i get this error-message...

what goes wrong?

thanks for your help..
heiko

Comment: remove Gemfile.lock and try

Comment: provide output of `which bundle`, `which ruby`, `bundle -v`

Comment: '/usr/local/bin/bundle'
'/usr/bin/ruby'
'Bundler version 1.6.2'

removing Gemfile.lock had no effect... same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to downgrade bundler or upgrade rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725811/how-to-downgrade-bundler-or-upgrade-rails)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following way and install again

```
gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler --version '1.0.0'
```

Specify bundler version according to application need.

**OR**

To update all your gems:

```
gem update --system
gem update
```